# How to log an entire request (headers, body, etc) using rails semantic logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-semantic-logger

I want to log any external API call `headers`, `body`, `params` to be automatically logged, i am using `rails_semantic_logger`, is there any configuration and customisation that will help my to log these details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below config in your `config/initializers/semantic_logger.rb`

```
SemanticLogger.configure do |config|
  # existing configuration

  config.add_appender(
    io: STDOUT,
    level: :debug,
    formatter: proc { |_, _, _, payload|
      "#{payload[:method]} #{payload[:url]}\n" \
      "Headers: #{payload[:headers].inspect}\n" \
      "Body: #{payload[:body]}\n" \
      "Params: #{payload[:params].inspect}\n"
    }
  )
end
```

Now you can log as mentioned below

```
# Make an API call
response = HTTParty.get('https://api.example.com/users', headers: { 'Authorization' => 'Bearer token' })

# Log the API call
logger.debug('External API call', method: response.request.http_method, url: response.request.last_uri.to_s, headers: response.request.headers, body: response.request.body, params: response.request.params)
```

I hope this will help you.